# Insert Select Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Ligação e `Historico_ligacao`

Tenho um *script* que copia todos os dados da tabela `Ligacao` para `Historico_ligacao`.

Quando comparo os dados entre as tebalas, a tabela `historico_ligacao` esta ordernado de uma forma diferente da `Ligacao`, não sei se isso influência em alguma coisa, mas gostaria que a ordenação de ambas fossem iguais.

Segue abaixo o código do *insert*:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT HISTORICO_LIGACAO ON
INSERT HISTORICO_LIGACAO (CDLIGACAO,CDLOTE,CDATRIBUTOLOTE,CDCAMPANHA,CDROTA,CDCONTATO,CDTELEFONE,CDESTADOLIGACAO,DURACAO,DTINICIO,DTFINAL,NUMERO_DISCADO,TECLAS_VALIDAS,TECLAS_TODAS, timezone)
output inserted.CDLIGACAO into #temp (num)
SELECT * FROM LIGACAO WHERE CDLOTE <= @CDLOTE order by cdligacao;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT HISTORICO_LIGACAO OFF
```

[image: printscreen do resultset]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie índice clusterizado na coluna `CDLIGACAO`

Se os registros forem únicos coloca ela também como chave primária.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_name ON HISTORICO_LIGACAO (CDLIGACAO);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Junior Torres a ordem de apresentação não influencia em nada. Mas se você quer exibi-los de maneira organizada, você pode utilizar a instrução **order by**. No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM LIGACAO ORDER BY CDLIGACAO;
SELECT * FROM HISTORICO_LIGACAO ORDER BY CDLIGACAO;
```